# Run gRPC server on iOS

Tags: ios, grpc

Is it possible to run a gRPC server on iOS?

Let’s say we want to use the gRPC framework to define APIs etc. And now we want to deploy a gRPC server in the same process with the application using it — connection via an InprocessChannel.

Is there a gRPC port for iOS that allows to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unlike with the Objective-C bindings for gRPC, it's possible to run a gRPC server on iOS using [Swift GRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift):

> APIs and generated code is provided for both gRPC clients and servers,
>   and can be built either with Xcode or the Swift Package Manager.
>   Support is provided for all four gRPC API styles (Unary, Server
>   Streaming, Client Streaming, and Bidirectional Streaming) and
>   connections can be made either over secure (TLS) or insecure channels.

The [Echo example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/tree/master/Examples/Echo) contains a Mac app that demonstrates both server and client code. The Swift gRPC parts should be similar in an iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not officially supported by gRPC, but you have a couple of options to do this on your own:

- You can wrap gRPC C++ and use their server feature. Someone tried this before and seems worked.
- You can use the [gRPC Swift repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift) which has gRPC server feature on iOS client.